# Printing from IE10 is different than other browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a div where I declare the size in an absolute size. It prints fine in IE8, Chrome and FF. When I print in IE10, it is almost 1/2 the size. I've googled and can't figure this one out.

Here is the markup I'm using:

```
<div class="printIdContainer" id="printIdContainer" style="width: 3.5in; height: 2in"> 
    <table width="100%"><tr><td>....yes, tables are evil</td></tr></table> 
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In IE10, have you changed the zoom level, or perhaps changed the "View"->"Text size" setting to something other than "Medium"?

Comment: Verified zoom is 100%. Couldn't find any other settings that could affect this.

Comment: In Windows Control Panel->Display, do you have the "Make it easier to read what's on your screen" set to 100%? I'm wondering if Windows is seeing an inch as something other than what the other browsers are using, and IE10 is using that information when printing.

Comment: It's set to 'Smaller-100% (default)'

Comment: Have you tried using [CSS @media media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) to differentiate between screen and printer output?

Comment: Yes. I'm using a print css with the following media tag:  MEDIA="print, handheld"